# Does friction help a car travel faster for a given radius on a banked track?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, centripetal-force

I was trying to do [this question](https://www.uwgb.edu/fenclh/problems/dynamics/circular/2/) and my original attempt went like this:
[image: working out]

I see that my mistake was that I assumed that after friction is accounted for, the car will be pulled down into the same lane as if it were travelling at the given design speed (15.6464 m/s) AND that it would travel at the design speed.

So, my question is, does the force of friction *not* affect the speed of a car on a banked track at all, and only change what lane it travels in (the radius of its path)? Or does it also affect the speed?
Can you travel in the same lane as the design speed lane but at a faster speed to what the centripetal acceleration formula ($mv^2/r$) allows for that given radius, with the help of friction pulling you downwards?

Comment: You can travel higher speed than the speed allowed by friction if its a level surface by centripetal force because banking of surface creates frictions $sin$ component towards the same direction as centripetal force  hence allowing more room for velocity

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I am not talking about level surfaces. I am asking whether friction allows you to go faster than the design speed for a given radius on a banked track.

Comment: Kinetic friction resists motion of car and gives a design speed , static friction and normal reaction's $\sin$ component will be the centripetal force for the car's turn and given m and r constant thus helps increasing the "v" value in the banked road

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

from the FBD

$$F_r+m\,g\sin(\beta)=\frac{m\,v^2}{r}\cos(\beta)$$
with $~F_r=\mu\,m\,g\,\cos(\beta)~$ you obtain the speed of the car $~v~$ .

$$v^2=r\,g\,(\mu+\tan(\beta))$$

this means that the speed  that the car can go **with out sliding** is higher that with out friction  (parameter $~\mu~$).